# SELECT id where min or max value from multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm looking for a fast MySQL query **that returns the id** of the product with the lowest (`min`) or highest (`max`) price, compared to all price categories (`a, b, c` and `d`).

I have a product table called `chocolate_stock` with several price categories. It's pretty easy to receive the lowest (`min`) or highest (`max`) price from a specific category (`a` or `b` or `c` or `d`).

```
id |      name       | price_a | price_b | price_c | price_d |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   Chips Ahoy    |   250   |   530   |   720   |   120 
--------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Chocolate Chunk |   250   |   90    |  32.92  |   110   
--------------------------------------------------------------
3  |      Oreo       |   103   |  44.52  |   250   |   850   
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The price categories are `decimal(10,2)`. Here's a sample that returns the highest price from the categories, *but* not the id:

```
$t = 'chocolate_stock';
$arrIds = array(1, 3);

$strQuery = "SELECT id, 
             MAX(price_a) AS price_a, 
             MAX(price_b) AS price_b, 
             MAX(price_c) AS price_c, 
             MAX(price_d) AS price_d 
             FROM $t WHERE id IN(". implode(',', array_map('intval', $arrIds)) .")";
```

What is the fastest way to retrieve this information?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: You expect two result records; given your example data and a query that would include all three items (i.e. without your WHERE clause):  min=(id:2, price_c:32.92) and max=(id:3, price_d:850) ?

Comment: Yes, I know. I can limit them later or reorder the results.

Comment: What is your desired output? Specifically what would you expect for MAX Price_a, where the max price is 250, and there are two products with this price?

Comment: If speed is important, normalize your data. Oh, and price categories are decimal(10,2)? Remind me not to but Oreos from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does what you want:

```
(select t.*
 from $t t
 where . . .
 order by price_a desc
 limit 1) union all
 (select t.*
 from $t t
 where . . .
 order by price_b desc
 limit 1) union all
(select t.*
 from $t t
 where . . .
 order by price_c desc
 limit 1) union all
(select t.*
 from $t t
 where . . .
 order by price_d desc
 limit 1)
```

If you have an index on `id` it should perform reasonably well.

That approach requires four passes through the table (although the index on `id` should greatly reduce that).  The following approach requires only one pass through the table:

```
select MAX(price_a),
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by price_a desc), ',', 1),
       max(price_b),
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by price_b desc), ',', 1),
       max(price_c),
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by price_c desc), ',', 1),
       max(price_d),
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by price_d desc), ',', 1)
from $t
where . . .
```

It uses a trick with `group_concat()` and `substring_index()` to get the max id for each of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you were to tabulate what you want your output to look like, but I think the piece you are missing is the HAVING clause.

first - try this

```
select min(id), max(price_a) from $t having price_a = max(price_a)
```

Then try

```
select min(id), min(price_a) from $t having price_a = min(price_a)
union
select min(id), max(price_a) from $t having price_a = max(price_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you would want to do is normalise your data, for ease of later querying I would create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW NormalT
AS
    SELECT  ID, Name, 'Price_a' AS Type, Price_a AS Price
    FROM    T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ID, Name, 'Price_b' AS Type, Price_b AS Price
    FROM    T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ID, Name, 'Price_c' AS Type, Price_c AS Price
    FROM    T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ID, Name, 'Price_d' AS Type, Price_d AS Price
    FROM    T;
```

Then I am not sure of the format you want, if you want the min an max for each price you could use this:

```
SELECT  mt.Type2,
        mt.Type,
        mt.Price,
        t.ID,
        t.Name
FROM    (   SELECT  Type, MIN(Price) AS Price, 'MIN' AS Type2
            FROM    NormalT
            GROUP BY Type
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Type, MAX(Price) AS Price, 'MAX' AS Type2
            FROM    NormalT
            GROUP BY Type
        ) mt
        INNER JOIN NormalT T
            ON mt.Type = T.Type
            AND mt.Price = t.Price
ORDER BY mt.Type2, mt.Type, t.ID;
```

Which will output the following from your sample data:

```
TYPE2   TYPE        PRICE   ID  NAME
MAX     Price_a     250     1   Chips Ahoy
MAX     Price_a     250     2   Chocolate Chunk
MAX     Price_b     530     1   Chips Ahoy
MAX     Price_c     720     1   Chips Ahoy
MAX     Price_d     850     3   Oreo
MIN     Price_a     103     3   Oreo
MIN     Price_b     44.52   3   Oreo
MIN     Price_c     32.92   2   Chocolate Chunk
MIN     Price_d     110     2   Chocolate Chunk
```

However, if it is just the min and max of all prices (a, b, c and d) then you could use this:

```
SELECT  mt.Type2,
        t.Type,
        mt.Price,
        t.ID,
        t.Name
FROM    (   SELECT  MIN(Price) AS Price, 'MIN' AS Type2
            FROM    NormalT
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  MAX(Price) AS Price, 'MAX' AS Type2
            FROM    NormalT
        ) mt
        INNER JOIN NormalT T
            ON mt.Price = t.Price;
```

Which will output this:

```
TYPE2   TYPE    PRICE       ID  NAME
MIN     Price_c     32.92   2   Chocolate Chunk
MAX     Price_d     850     3   Oreo
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cca3b/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this , It's emulating Analytics as MYSQL doesn't have them by default :

```
SELECT id, 
             ( select MAX(price_a) from $t t2 where  t2.id = t1.id ) AS price_a, 
             ( select MAX(price_b) from $t t2 where  t2.id = t1.id ) AS price_b, 
             ( select MAX(price_c) from $t t2 where  t2.id = t1.id ) AS price_c, 
             ( select MAX(price_d) from $t t2 where  t2.id = t1.id ) AS price_d 
             FROM $t t1 WHERE id IN(". implode(',', array_map('intval', $arrIds)) .")
```

Source From : http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=3

Answer (score -1):

You are not getting id because, MAX returns one value. But it is not so with id.You can use seperate queries like

```
SELECT id,MAX(price_a) FROM $t WHERE id IN (". implode(',', array_map('intval', $arrIds)).")";
SELECT id,MAX(price_b) FROM $t WHERE id IN (". implode(',', array_map('intval', $arrIds)).")";
```

etc

Comment: Thank you. Isn't this possible within one *single* query ?

Comment: No. It is not. That is because MAX, MIN, AVG and all return a single record. Not multiple. For your cause, you'll need multiple IDs with maximum and minimum price from each region. That is not possible.